# A basic date and time selector for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, datetimepicker

I cant seem to find a simple, good date AND time picker for use in AngularJS. There are some for Javascript, but not that many that i can find (combodate seems okay).

But to keep it simple, i am thinking i wann make a simple dropdown with dates, for the next 30 days and the last 30 days. How would that look, code-wise?
Also, i need a seperarte dropdown for the time. I am thinking of doing one dropdown, and instead of displaying every minute option in teh 24 hours, displaying each 15 minute. So it would display: "00:00, 00:15, 00:30" etc.

Any ideas?

I know there is a bootstrap directive for it, but i am not using bootstrap in this solution, and i do not want to use bootstrap in this solution, so i was looking for a clean solution.

Comment: How about bootstrap datetime picker.https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I am not using bootstrap in this project :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using angularui bootstrap. 
Please go through the below links. Hope these will help u.

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker
```

Also for timepicker u can make a table with the records of all possible time with desired interval. Then the records of that table can be showed in dropdown

Comment: I am not using bootstrap and i do not want to use it. So i was looking for a clean solution

Comment: Then go through this  : [link](https://rawgit.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker/master/index.html) Also for 15 minute interval u can add step = 15 in the code

Comment: Thats the one i am using now, but it does not work in IE 11 and below :-(

Comment: sorry...den u should search for any alternative to make it working in IE11 n below. Also the working demo is [here]: https://plnkr.co/edit/VJtryQTDn4H6QajYqR21?p=preview